# How to handle print output from yahoo-finance quote reader?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, trading, pandas-datareader

I'm designing a tool that will help me manage risk in my equities portfolio. I've got some code that gathers current price data from yahoo finance for 4 equities, 2x longs and 2x shorts. This is using the yahoo-finance tool.

I can gather the data but I can't work out how to divide the prices by each other to return the value of the spread (stockA/stockB as a relative value trade)

```
#always helpful to show the version:
(env) LaurencsonsiMac:~ admin$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin



from yahoo_finance import Share
>>> L1 = Share('YHOO')
>>> L2 = Share('GOOG')
>>> S1 = Share('AAPL')
>>> S2 = Share('MSFT')
>>> print L1.get_price()
50.55
>>> print S1.get_price()
154.45
```

A small victory! I can fetch the price :) but
I dont know how to manipulate this output as an object and define Long1 as “whatever is returned by print L1.get_price()”
The final output would be a table like this, with the spread values as a single (super important!) number to two or three (whatever) decimal places.

```
Position, Spread
YHOO/AAPL, 0.327 #value of Yahoo stock price/Apple stock price
GOOG/MSF,  4.55
ticker/ticker, 10.14
ticker/ticker, 0.567
```

I attempted to define Long1 and Short1 as the number that L1.get_price() prints:

```
>>> Long1 = "L1.get_price()"
>>> Short1 = "S2.get_price()"
```

then hopefully I should get a number by dividing those two:

```
>>> Long1/Short1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

so i tried to convert these numbers to a float [because it might work why not] but I’m clearly misunderstanding something:

```
>>> float(Long1)/float(Short1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: L1.get_price()
```

Alternatively I did manage to get an output using this piece of code using the pandas module: (thank you Brad Solomon for this:)

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web

def get_quotes(symbols, type='dict'):
    quotes = web.get_quote_yahoo(symbols)['last']
    if type == 'dict':
        quotes = quotes.to_dict() # otherwise, Series
    return quotes

quotes = get_quotes(symbols=['RAD', 'MSFT']); quotes
Out[16]: {'MSFT': 70.409999999999997, 'RAD': 3.46}
```

But how would you realise MSFT / RAD, get python to "read the string"?

I'm really quite stuck, can anyone hint me how I can get my quoted prices into real objects I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Variable assignment for *Long1* and *Short1* is wrong: instead of calling methods, you assign string literals with the names of the function. Try to change them to:

```
>>> Long1 = L1.get_price()
>>> Short1 = S2.get_price()
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the values in quotes is telling Python that it is a String datatype. Using that you are dividing which will fail. Even when using the function float since the value is actually a string and not the value of expression that you might be hoping it to be resulting in failing the function call inside quotes.
You do not need to use quotes and direct function calls should do the trick.

```
>>> Long1 = L1.get_price()

>>> Short1 = S2.get_price()
```